# Hive Client Install Fail

Tags: hive, hortonworks-data-platform, ubuntu-18.04, ambari

Using Ubuntu 18.04, Installing Hortonworks Data Platform using Ambari 2.7.3.0 gets stuck at `Hive Client Install` then fail after almost 30 minutes with the following error

```
2019-02-18 13:20:20,369 - File['/tmp/tmpFVEJd6'] {'content': StaticFile('/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ambari-hdp-1.list')}
2019-02-18 13:20:20,370 - Writing File['/tmp/tmpFVEJd6'] because contents don't match
2019-02-18 13:20:20,383 - Package['unzip'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
2019-02-18 13:20:20,517 - Skipping installation of existing package unzip
2019-02-18 13:20:20,517 - Package['curl'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
2019-02-18 13:20:20,638 - Skipping installation of existing package curl
2019-02-18 13:20:20,639 - Package['hdp-select'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
2019-02-18 13:20:20,782 - Skipping installation of existing package hdp-select
2019-02-18 13:20:20,788 - The repository with version 3.1.0.0-78 for this command has been marked as resolved. It will be used to report the version of the component which was installed
2019-02-18 13:20:21,675 - Using hadoop conf dir: /usr/hdp/3.1.0.0-78/hadoop/conf
2019-02-18 13:20:21,765 - call['ambari-python-wrap /usr/bin/hdp-select status hive-server2'] {'timeout': 20}
2019-02-18 13:20:21,866 - call returned (0, 'hive-server2 - 3.1.0.0-78')
2019-02-18 13:20:21,866 - Stack Feature Version Info: Cluster Stack=3.1, Command Stack=None, Command Version=3.1.0.0-78 -> 3.1.0.0-78
2019-02-18 13:20:21,938 - File['/var/lib/ambari-agent/cred/lib/CredentialUtil.jar'] {'content': DownloadSource('http://ip-172-31-16-181:8080/resources/CredentialUtil.jar'), 'mode': 0755}
2019-02-18 13:20:21,939 - Not downloading the file from http://ip-172-31-16-181:8080/resources/CredentialUtil.jar, because /var/lib/ambari-agent/tmp/CredentialUtil.jar already exists
2019-02-18 13:20:45,289 - Package['hive-3-1-0-0-78'] {'retry_on_repo_unavailability': False, 'retry_count': 5}
2019-02-18 13:20:46,021 - Installing package hive-3-1-0-0-78 ('/usr/bin/apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef --allow-unauthenticated --assume-yes install hive-3-1-0-0-78')

Command failed after 1 tries
```